# How to count rows with specific value in Sequelize?

Tags: sql, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a mysql table and I use sequelize to query it in node.js. How to count all rows with specific value? This is the code:

```
const data = await db.models.fruits.findAll({
    where: { type: `fresh` },
    group: `title`,
    attributes: [`title`, [Sequelize.fn(`COUNT`, `title`), `title`]]
})

const rows = data.map(el => el.get({ plain: true }))
console.log(rows)
```

In my console I get the result:

```
[ { title: 17 }, { title: 15 } ]
```

It counts correct. But my question is: How I should transform Sequelize code to get result like this:

```
[ { orange: 17 }, { apple: 15 } ]
```

Comment: can you also add the table you are querying

Comment: Show the generated SQL in the post

Comment: You need to indicate a different alias for `Sequelize.fn`

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` to transform the fruit property into the title and the count property to the value. e.g: if the data array contains `{ fruit: 'orange', count: 17 }` and `{ fruit: 'apple', count: 15 }`, the rows array will contain `{ orange: 17 }` and `{ apple: 15 }`.

```
const data = await db.models.fruits.findAll({
  where: { type: `fresh` },
  group: `title`,
  attributes: [
    [Sequelize.literal(`title`), `fruit`],
    [Sequelize.fn(`COUNT`, `title`), `count`]
  ]
});

const rows = data.map(el => {
  const obj = {};
  obj[el.get(`fruit`)] = el.get(`count`);
  return obj;
});

console.log(rows);
```